# Triangulated categories generated by a collection of submodules

Tags: ct.category-theory, triangulated-categories

In the book "Cohomology Rings of Finite Groups", by Carlson- Townsley - Elizondo there is the following corollary

> The category $\mathsf{stmod}_{\mathbb{k}G}$ is generated as a triangulated category by the collection of modules induced by the elementary abelian $p$-subgroups.

where $G$ is a finite group, and $\mathbb{k}$ is a field of positive characteristic. My question has to do with the part *"...is generated as a triangulated category..."*. Because I couldn't find it out inside the book a definition or explanation of it, can you please explain me what does that mean?

References are welcomed too.

Comment: There is no proper triangulated subcategory containing all of them, I guess - what else could it be? Maybe "thick" instead of "triangulated"...